# Importing data from MS Access

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ms-access, etl

Is there a way to export data out of MS Access to another database? I know data can be exported out of access but I'm looking for a way to once a day pull data out of MS Access tables and upload it into a SQL database like  PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: Simply export tables into flat files (xml, csv, txt, xlsx) and import into other RDMS. Alternatively, if you have MSAccess.exe, you can link table from other RDMS's and migrate with SQL queries. MS Access defaults to Jet/ACE SQL Engine (Windows .dll files).

Comment: I think import is the problem, because you have to adapt the datatypes (e.g. boolean is a tinyint in MySQL): I think the the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard does most of the work for you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-access.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out. I used Talend Open Studio for Data Integration. It has a connector for Microsoft Access which lets you write to access, create, or read from access.

Answer (score 0):

You could export from M$ to csv

then use this command to import the data into postgresql using either **pgadmin** or **plsql**

```
copy your_created_table FROM '/your/path/to/file.csv' USING DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```